# How to determine the best Photoshop version for my computer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I downloaded Photoshop CC 2015.5 (17.0) trial on my laptop, and its system requirements are satisfied although, when it opens, it says that there is a problem with my graphics card, I went to the support page provided in the error message and it appears that they don't support certain older graphics cards, which mine is one of.

In another support page, it says that some features will not work properly or not work at all in this case.

What version of Photoshop can I use that can work fine with my laptop? Giving that Photoshop CC 2015 didn't show this problem but, Isn't 2015.5 just an update?

My graphics cards are Intel HD Graphics 4000 AMD Radeon HD 7670M.

Comment: Well for one, CS3 was the last light version of Photoshop. It's missing some fancy new features obviously, but most of them I still don't use in CC.

Comment: You could try disabling the use of the graphics processor as detailed at [How do I use the Performance preferences for the graphics processor in Photoshop?](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cc-gpu-card-faq.html#topic-4). Some operations (which you might not use anyway) will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can do research some minimum and recommended specs on certain version.

Oh, one more thing, the AMD stuff are have strange behavior on some software that requires graphic card to do their job. Have you tried to configure the AMD software? Like adding Photoshop to full power mode for the graphic card?

I suggest you to try CS6 Or CC 2013.